# How to combine parts of different columns in a DataFrame?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Say I have a DataFrame:

```
     foo   bar
0    1998  abc
1    1999  xyz
2    2000  123
```

What is the best way to combine the first two (or any n) characters of foo with the last two of bar to make a third column `19bc, 19yz, 2023` ? Normally to combine columns I'd simply do

```
df['foobar'] = df['foo'] + df['bar']
```

but I believe I can't do slicing on these objects.

Comment: df['foo'].str[:2] + df['bar'].str[-2:]

Comment: @RaymondKwok. Your answer raises an `AttributeError` exception because the `foo` column has `int64` dtype and the `str` accessor is not available in this case.

Comment: I think the message is, we need `df['foo'].astype(str)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you convert your columns as string with `astype`, you can use `str` accessor and slice values:

```
df['foobar'] = df['foo'].astype(str).str[:2] + df['bar'].str[-2:]
print(df)

# Ouput
    foo  bar foobar
0  1998  abc   19bc
1  1999  xyz   19yz
2  2000  123   2023
```

Using `astype(str)` is useless if your column has already `object` dtype like `bar` column (?).

You can read: [Working with text data](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/text.html)

Answer (score 1):

Example:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"foo": [1998, 1999, 2000], "bar": ["abc", "xyz", "123"]})
df["foobar"] = df.apply(lambda x: str(x["foo"])[0:2] + x["bar"][1:], axis=1)
print(df)
#     foo  bar foobar
# 0  1998  abc   19bc
# 1  1999  xyz   19yz
# 2  2000  123   2023
```

Comment: No need for an `apply`. Better use the answer in comment above.

Comment: In this case, especially for strings, apply might offer more speed

Comment: @MayankPorwal. The answer in comment is incomplete. It raises an error because the `foo` column has not `object` dtype.

Comment: The answer below this is better.

Comment: thanks! this answer was also helpful